# Save a pointer address in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers

I want to save a certain address of a pointer, and use it later.

This is the struct which holds the original pointer:

```
typedef struct CSV
{
    char *RD;
    ...
}CSV;
```

This is the called function:

```
static status_t write_to_buffer(CSV *CSVUtil,...)
{

    // The way i was planning to save address:
    char* temp =  &CSVUtil->RD;

...
    // pointer location ++
    CSVUtil->RD++;
...
    // The way i wanted to restore it:
    &CSVUtil->RD = temp;
}
```

First, am i doing the address restoring as needed?

I get this error message: `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`

So i'm guessing i'm not, But what can i do to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, what i want to do is to copy the address to a certain pointer, change the used address (increment it), and than set back the copied address to the used address.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment is incorrect:

```
char* temp =  &CSVUtil->RD;
```

The expression `&CSVUtil->RD` returns a pointer to a character pointer (i.e. `char**`), but you are assigning it to a character pointer `char*`, so one level of indirection is missing. There should be a compiler warning in the output telling you about this problem.

The reason the assignment back `&CSVUtil->RD = temp` does not work is that the result of the "take address `&`" operator is not assignable. You can obtain an address, but you cannot change it by "assigning" it a new address.

It looks like you need to save and restore the pointer itself, not the location of that pointer. Therefore, you can fix the code by removing the ampersands:

```
char* temp =  CSVUtil->RD;
...
CSVUtil->RD = temp;
```

Comment: Looking at the use case, it seems as though what he really wants, is to copy the value of the pointer first, so that he can increment it, and then he won't need to restore the temporary at the end.

Answer (score 2):

According to your problem

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

That means that your are trying to assign a value to a const or an Un-Changeable type.

Now lets take a look at the assignments you have:

1. char* temp =  &CSVUtil->RD;
2. CSVUtil->RD++;
3. &CSVUtil->RD = temp;

A Pointer as you know, holds an address so if i have a:

> char *pointer

The pointer variable will hold the address where the actual value i want is, and to access that value i would either use *pointer = XXX or if it's a struct pointer->inside-value = XXX.

What you are trying to do by adding the "&" in front of the pointer is to actually give back the location of "pointer" variable which was declared.

So - instead of getting the address of the value that RD is pointing to, you get the address of RD itself. 
ALSO and here is the problem - Addresses of variables cannot be changed this way but through malloc as it's being decided in compilation or runtime if it's dynamic (malloc) so when doing &Pointer = XXXX you are actually aren't changing the variable but trying to change it's address so to speak. BUT the "&" operator just returns the address (think of it like a function that returns an int that specifies address) so it cannot be changed.

I would change the assignments to:

1. char *temp = CSVUtil->RD;
2. Is ok;
3. CSVUtil->RD = temp;

That should work.

Hope my explanation was good enough.